# HTML page interaction with RestX website

Tags: html, rest

I'm totally new to RESTful API and html and was wondering if I could get some advice.

Basically, I've made an application with a restful api using RestX, see picture, that can succesfully retrieve info, like a list of strings with node addresses.  [image]

And I want to make a HTML page that looks roughly like this (mockup):

[image]

I'm totally unsure how to actually do this however. Also, I'm unsure of how to display, for example, the list of strings I've received. In the mockup, the list of registered nodes should dynamically be made from the list received from the application, for example.

I've made a sample HTML text file (from another overflow post), but that doesn't really do anything...
See code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="the/Path/To/The/Downloaded/JQuery.js"></script>
    <script>
        //Usually, you put script-tags into the head
        function myFunction() {
            //This performs a POST-Request.
            //Use "$.get();" in order to perform a GET-Request (you have to take a look in the rest-API-documentation, if you're unsure what you need)
            //The Browser downloads the webpage from the given url, and returns the data.
            $.get( "http://192.168.59.130:8080/api/@/ui/api-docs/#/operation/list/GET/___list___nodes", function( data ) {
                 //As soon as the browser finished downloading, this function is called.
                 $('#demo').html(data);
                 alert( "Load was performed." );

            });
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <p>Click the button to trigger a function.</p>

    <button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>

    <p id="demo"></p>    
</body>
</html>
```

I'm lost, can anybody help?

Answer (score 0):

Currently you are not using the REST APIs, but the URLs to access Restx UI interface. 
The first thing you should do is to update the URL you are using to something like: http://192.168.59.130:8080/api/list/nodes

You'll get back a list of entities (at least, that's what the name of the API method suggests) in json that you can use in your javascript to populate the HTML form.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this tomorrow (server running the application is down atm). Any suggestions for recreating the mockup?

Comment: Did you succeeded with the RestX APIs? 

In our projects when we need nice UI we usually go for Bootstrap (http://getbootstrap.com) and Angular.js (https://angularjs.org/), but that's really a personal choice.